# Songhai embarked unit defense

Tags: civilization-5

Embarked units can defend themselves.

> **Special Ability: River Warlord:**
>
> - Triple gold from Barbarian    encampments and pillaging Cities.
> - Embarked units can defend themselves.

1. What is the defensive rating given?
2. Does it depend on the unit?
3. Does it effect bombardment, ships
   'stepping' on the unit or both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really have an answer for (1) and (2), but I'll list my thoughts anyway in case it can help. If anyone can provide a more complete answer I will delete mine.

1. The defensive rating is astronomical - 500 if I remember correctly. I'm not sure why that is - the actual rating is much lower, embarked units are pretty susceptible to ranged attacks. I don't know what the actual rating is.
2. I don't know, I think it doesn't.
3. The main benefit of the promotion is that ships can no longer move into the tile occupied by the embarked units and instantly destroy it - so the only way an embarked unit gets killed is by ranged attacks.

Comment: Strange. Seems super strong for a map with a lot of water!

Comment: The 500 defense thing is one of the fixes listed in the latest patch.